# Click button and send command to execute on xterm.js terminal

Tags: javascript, terminal, pty, xtermjs

I want to click a button and send a linux command such as "ls" to be executed on xterm.js terminal. Is there a way to do this?

Pty pseudo-terminal written in Go is running remotely and I'm using xterm.js as the front end component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should take care of the case mentioned above

In HTML

```
<button (click)="runCmd('ls')>ls</button>
```

In app.component.ts

Assuming there is a websocket server that is listening to the end point mentioned here...

```
public runCmd(command){
  var url = "ws://<ip>:<port>/pty"
  var terminal = new Terminal()
  terminal.open(document.getElementById("terminalDiv");
  var socket = new WebSocket(url);
  var attachAddon = new AttachAddon(socket);
  terminal.loadAddon(attachAddon);

  //socket.send() will send the data passed to it. 
  socket.send(command);
}
```

Comment: Any way to have a real dialog with the terminal session?

Comment: any idea with the url used for web socket as it is showing error?

Answer (score 1):

I did this same thing with Python sending a command from the app to the embedded xterm.js terminal and one thing i recommend is setting it up so you can send the raw command without special escaping needed.

I found this javscript "heredoc" function which allowed me to send the raw complex multiline oneliners to xterm.js without issue. leaving this here in case anyone else finds it useful.

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def run_command_via_js_double_click(self, signal):
        # send a command to the server
        script = """
        var cmd = (function() {/*%s*/}).toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];
            wssh.send(cmd);
        """ % cmd_replaced
        self.currentWidget().page().runJavaScript(script)
```

Can see an example of it in action below.

[image]